# Batch Script Errorlevel, GOTO and IF LOOP

Tags: batch-file, goto

I would like to check the status of two log files using the below content.

```
SET/A WAITCNT=0
    :WAIT
    SET /a WAIT_TIME=%ADMIN_TIME%/%TIME_OUT%
    IF %WAITCNT% GTR %WAIT_TIME% GOTO PROBLEM 
    SET/A WAITCNT=%WAITCNT%+1   
    TIMEOUT /T %TIME_OUT% /nobreak 
    FINDSTR /C:"<Running>" %HOME_1%\%LOG_FILE%
    if %ERRORLEVEL%=="0" ( 
    ( 
        GOTO :LOG
    ) 
    ELSE GOTO WAIT

:LOG
IF %JDA_LOG_FILE%="" GOTO WWF_1
SET/A WAITCNT=0
     :WAIT
     SET /a WAIT_TIME=%ADMIN_TIME%/%TIME_OUT%
    IF %WAITCNT% GTR %WAIT_TIME% GOTO PROBLEM 
    SET/A WAITCNT=%WAITCNT%+1   
    TIMEOUT /T %TIME_OUT% /nobreak 
    FINDSTR /C:"<RUNNING>" %HOME_1%\%LOG_FILE%
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" ( 
    ( 
        GOTO END
    ) 
    ELSE GOTO WAIT
```

It looks it is just executing at the first if loop itself and it is not going to the second loop because of goto/call (i'm not sure). can you please help?

Comment: The else keyword has to be on the same line as the if/the closing parentheses of the code block. And your opening / closing parentheses count doesn't match.

Answer (score 3):

```
if %ERRORLEVEL%=="0" GOTO :LOG
```

how should `%errorlevel%` (without quotes) ever be identical to the string `"0"` (with quotes)?

Use either

```
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO :LOG
```

or

```
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 GOTO :LOG
```

(besides the syntax failure with `ELSE` aready mentioned by LotPings - I would not use parantheses if there is just a single command)

Another hint: `set /a` doesn't need the percent signs: `set /a var=var+1` is perfectly valid. And there is another syntax for incrementing a variable:

```
set /a var+=1
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides some syntax issues you have in your code (listed below), a main problem is that you have two identical labels defined: `:WAIT`. [`goto`](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html), as well as [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) (when used with a label), scan the batch file from the current line position downwards for the given label, and when the end of the file is reached, the scanning continues at the beginning of the file towards the current line position. Therefore, even if the syntax issues were resolved, you would not have two loops; instead, the first `goto :WAIT` would jump to the second label `:WAIT`, and the second `goto :WAIT` would jump to the first `:WAIT`, what is not what you expect most likely.

The solution is quite simple: rename the labels (or at least one of them) to avoid duplicates:

```cmd
set /A WAITCNT=0
:WAIT_1
    set /A WAIT_TIME=ADMIN_TIME/TIME_OUT
    if %WAITCNT% gtr %WAIT_TIME% goto :PROBLEM
    set /A WAITCNT+=1
    timeout /T %TIME_OUT% /NOBREAK
    findstr /I /C:"<Running>" "%HOME_1%\%LOG_FILE%"
    if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
        goto :LOG
    ) else (
        goto :WAIT_1
    )

:LOG
if "%JDA_LOG_FILE%"=="" GOTO :WWF_1
set /A WAITCNT=0
:WAIT_2
    set /A WAIT_TIME=ADMIN_TIME/TIME_OUT
    if %WAITCNT% gtr %WAIT_TIME% goto :PROBLEM
    set /A WAITCNT+=1
    timeout /T %TIME_OUT% /NOBREAK
    findstr /I /C:"<Running>" "%HOME_1%\%LOG_FILE%"
    if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
        goto :END
    ) else (
        goto :WAIT_2
    )
```

Syntax issues:

- the `if`/`else` structure is wrong; there are unbalanced parentheses, and `else` must appear in the same line as the closing parenthesis after the first conditional command(s), either as shown above, or in a single line, like: `if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (goto :LOG) else (goto :WAIT_1)`; in this single-line approach, the parentheses around the command(s) after `else` are optional, the ones before however are required;
- as [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082) already pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51247844), `%ERRORLEVEL%` cannot equal `"0"` due to the quotes; since we are comparing integer values here, I recommend to unquote both sides and to use the operator `equ` rather than `==`;
- the comparison operator for checking `%JDA_LOG_FILE%` is `=`, although it should be `==`; the quotation is wrong as also for `%ERRORLEVEL%`, although this time, you need quotes on both sides as you are comparing strings; if `%JDA_LOG_FILE%` is empty and you have no quotes around, a syntax error is thrown;
- not an error, but still: `set /A` supports a `+=` operator to easily increment a variable; you also do not need the `%`-signs around variables in `set /A`;
- I recommend to quote the file name argument of `findstr` to avoid errors when there are spaces in it;
- I am not sure what you actually want to find by `findstr`:

  - is it the case-insensitive literal string `<Running>`?
    if yes, use: `findstr /I /C:"<Running>" "%HOME_1%\%LOG_FILE%"`;
  - do you want to find the *word* `Running` case-insensitively, so using word boundaries?
    if yes, use: `findstr /I "\<Running\>" "%HOME_1%\%LOG_FILE%"`;
  - do you want to do case-sensitive searches?
    if yes, just remove the `/I` from the above suggestions;

---

Since you have two (almost) identical loops, you could move the common part into a sub-routine, call it by `call` and provide the differing items as arguments. To avoid `goto :PROBLEM` to be executed in the sub-routine, you could let the sub-routine return an `ERRORLEVEL` whose state decides whether the `goto` command needs to be executed. Here is a possible way:

```cmd
rem // Call sub-routine and provide some arguments:
call :SUB_LOOP "<Running>" "%HOME_1%\%LOG_FILE%"
rem // Detect if `ErrorLevel` is set and go to `:PROBLEM` then:
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto :PROBLEM

:LOG
if "%JDA_LOG_FILE%"=="" GOTO :WWF_1
rem // Call sub-routine and provide some arguments:
call :SUB_LOOP "<Running>" "%HOME_1%\%LOG_FILE%"
rem // Detect if `ErrorLevel` is set and go to `:PROBLEM` then:
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto :PROBLEM

rem // This is required to avoid the sub-routine to be executed unintentionally:
goto :EOF


:SUB_LOOP
    set /A WAITCNT=0
    :WAIT
    set /A WAIT_TIME=ADMIN_TIME/TIME_OUT
    if %WAITCNT% gtr %WAIT_TIME% (
        rem // Set `ErrorLevel` to one here:
        (call)
        goto :EOF
    )
    set /A WAITCNT+=1
    timeout /T %TIME_OUT% /NOBREAK
    findstr /I /C:"%~1" "%~2"
    if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
        goto :WAIT
    )
    rem // `ErrorLevel` is zero at this point;
    goto :EOF
```